# Spring-5 ResponseEntity (no Creators, like default construct, exist)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jersey, jackson-databind

I am using Java 11 with spring-boot 2.1.3 version. I am consuming a 3rd party service in my code.

3rd party service is returning the org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity ( of org.springframework:spring-web:5.1.5.RELEASE).

Now I am getting issue while automatically unmarshling the 3rd party response as the ResponseEntity not having any default constructor.

**Pseudocode of 3rd party Service signature:**

```
 @POST
    public ResponseEntity<Abc> PostABC(){
// Some logic 
 return responseEntity;
}
```

**Pseudocode At consumer side:**

```
ResponseEntity<Abc> response = client.PostABC();
```

**Error:**

```
javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

**Why ResponseEntity is not having the Default Constructor?**
**How can I fix this isue?**

**NOTE:** I am getting LinkedHashMap as JSON is not able to translate to ResponseEntity

Comment: can you show the complete code with imports ?

Comment: so in some login when you create Abc , Abc should have a no-args constructor. else you need to define Jackson creators on Abc class.

Comment: You seem to be using a JAX-RS client and trying to deserialize to an object meant to be used with the Spring RestTemplate client. Also your pseudocode doesn't make much sense as you are using a JAX-RS annotation (@POST) and a Spring object (ResponseEntity). These two frameworks are different and you should separate the two so you don't get confused about what you can and cannot use.